# How to transport variables from one page to another

Tags: javascript, variables

I hope you can help me. I'm trying to send javascript variables inside my project, from one page to another but it doesn't work. I'll explain myself better:

I have the **index.html** with a form with two fields *(name and surname)*

```
<form method="post" action="main.html">
   <label>Name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
   <label>Surname: </label>
   <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

It sends me to **main.html** where there's a list with links to different forms.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="form1.html">Form 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="form2.html">Form 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="form3.html">Form 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let's say I pick the 1st option (Form 1) and it sends me to form1.html. I'd like to see something like this:
[Picture of 1st option form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJZK6.jpg)

The idea is to show a new form with new fields but transporting into  **name and surname** the values of the **name and surname** inputs of the form placed in **index.html**.

I've been trying for hours and I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: check local storage to keep your data in browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: It looks really useful for the problem I'm dealing with. I'll try that way. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @KamuranSönecek it works with your solution!!!!

Comment: your are  welcome @Jota

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be needing a backend language, like PHP or something, to transport variables to another page. Javascript doesn't work like that.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: thanks. I'll try with localStorage and if I have problems I'll try with php. thanks